# How to find the number of blobs in a 2d matrix?

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array, neighbours

How can I find the number of blobs in a 2d matrix? SIZE `MxN`

A blob is a block of continuous `X` pixels. where the matrix contains `X` and `O`

```
XOOOXO
OXOXOX
XXOOXO
```

I would like to use 8-neighbourship (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_connectivity#8-connected)). So I would expect 2 blobs to be found in above example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is simple: Mark each continuous blob and count how many blobs were marked.

Here is some pseudo-code (you did not specify a programming language) to get you started:

```
numBlobs = 0;
foreach(item in matrix)
{
    res = Visit(item);
    if(res > 0) 
    {
        numBlobs = numBlobs + 1;
    }
}
return numBlobs;
```

The Visit function/method looks like this:

```
Visit(item)
{
    marked = 0;
    if(item.IsX() && !IsItemMarked(neighbour))
    {
        MarkItemAsVisited(item);
        marked = 1;
        foreach(neighbour in GetNeighbours(item))
        {
            marked = marked + Visit(neighbour);
        }
    }
    return marked;
}
```

All you have to do is to implement the other fucntions/methods but they are pretty straightforward.

Comment: Please give it to me in C, it'll be more understandable!

Comment: @AkshayAgarwal Please do it yourself, it will be good practice.

Comment: Ohkay! Thanks a lot anyways!

Comment: I am doing something like this

inline 'char arr[10][10];
int blobCount=0;
for(i=0;i<row;i++)
{
for(j=0;j<col;j++)
{ 
res=visit(arr);
if(res>0)
{
blobCount++;
}
}
return blobCount;'


but I fail to understand the visit method. KINDLY HELP.

Comment: You need to pass i, j to Visit() in your case. I'll post an update later if there is time...

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matrix = new int[6][5];
        System.out.println(matrix.length);
        for (int i=0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }

        matrix[0][3] = 1;
        matrix[1][1] = 1;
        matrix[1][3] = 1;
        matrix[2][1] = 1;
        matrix[2][2] = 1;
        matrix[2][3] = 1;
        matrix[4][0] = 1;
        matrix[4][4] = 1;
        matrix[5][2] = 1;
        matrix[5][3] = 1;
        matrix[5][4] = 1;

        System.out.println(findBlobCount(matrix, matrix.length, matrix[0].length));
    }

    static int findBlobCount (int matrix[][], int rowCount, int colCount)
    {
        int visited[][] = new int[rowCount][colCount]; // all initialized to false

        int count=0;

        for (int i=0; i<rowCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<colCount; j++)
            {
                if (matrix[i][j] == 1 && visited[i][j] == 0) // unvisited black cell
                {
                    markVisited (i,j, matrix, visited, rowCount, colCount);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

        return count;
    }


    static int markVisited (int i, int j, int [][]matrix, int [][]visited, int rowCount, int colCount)
    {
        if (i < 0 || j < 0)
            return 0;

        if (i >= rowCount || j >= colCount)
            return 0;

        if (visited[i][j] == 1) // already visited
            return 1;

        if (matrix[i][j] == 0) // not a black cell
            return 0;

        visited[i][j] = 1;

        // recursively mark all the 4 adjacent cells - right, left, up and down
        return  markVisited (i+1, j, matrix, visited, rowCount, colCount) 
                + markVisited (i-1, j, matrix, visited, rowCount, colCount) 
                + markVisited (i, j+1, matrix, visited, rowCount, colCount) 
                + markVisited (i, j-1, matrix, visited, rowCount, colCount);
    }
```